# How to make a function use the data that is on the sheet, the function is written on?

Tags: excel, vba

Ill use an example to explain my problem. Lets say I write the function,

```
Function Sums()

Sums = Cells(1, 1) + Cells(1, 2)

End Function
```

Then, lets say I have two spreadsheets,  [A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MSZK.png) and [B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYW5c.png). If I refresh all spreadsheets while on A, the Sums() function on spreadsheet B, utilizes the data from spreadsheet A. How can I make the functions utilize the data specifically on the spreadsheet the function is written on?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is when using `Cells(1, 1)` or `Range("A1")` without specifying in which worksheet that is, Excel starts guessing which worksheet you mean. The result of that guessing may be different.

- Code in Module:
  when the code is in a module it assumes that you mean the `ActiveSheet` (the sheet which is on top at the moment the code runs)
- Code in Sheet:
  when the code is in a worksheet then it assumes that you mean that worksheet the code is in.

So we see any `Cells(1, 1)` or `Range("A1")` without specifying a worksheet is a bit lottery.

The next issue here is that the `Sums()` function can not know on which sheet it was written on unless you give the cells as parameters in a range:

```
Public Function Sums(Rng As Range) As Double 'specify a return type here
    Sums = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng)
End Function
```

So you can use it in a cell like: `=Sums(A1:B1)`

Another advantage is that you don't need to press re-calculate, because it watches if the values in the given range `Rng` changed and automatically recalculates then.

**Note: A function should always use the parameters given to the function instead of accessing the worksheet directly. Otherwise the function might show wrong values (unless you make it volatile).**

Comment: Ill take a look into that for my actual project that I am doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. But here is a guess: Be sure to always (fully) define your worksheets.

```
Function Sums()
  Dim wb as Workbook
  Dim ws as Worksheet
  Dim ws2 as Worksheet
  Dim sum as Integer
  Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

  'now you defined your worksheets and always know which cells you're referring to 
  sum = ws.Cells(1, 1) + ws2.Cells(1, 2)
End Function
```

Also I generally recommend to use ranges, instead of Cells(x,y). Let me know if this answers the question

Comment: defining a `sum as Integer` is no good idea. Imagine the cells contain `1.1` and `2.5` and your result is wrong. Also this function doesn't return anything, so instead of defining a `sum` variable better use `Function Sums() As Double` and return the sum `Sums = ws.Cells(1, 1) + ws2.Cells(1, 2)`

Comment: You're absolutely right @Pᴇʜ - I just copy pasted and extended, as I only wanted to make the point of defining the worksheets

Comment: This does answer my question. Thanks!